# Having errors with on click function to show/hide content

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I have two dynamically created components and Im working on a onClick function to show content.  The problem that I am having is during the onClick event my code is showing all content.  What I am looking for is when I click index 1 of my first component, I want to show index 1 of my second component and hide the rest and when I click on the next index, I show the next index of my second component.  Appreciate any help or suggestions to make it better.

```
showContent(){
    const container = document.querySelector('ne-card-slider').shadowRoot;
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('ne-main-content').shadowRoot;
    const card = container.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.anchor');
    const content = wrapper.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.contentMain');
    //console.log(content);
    //console.log(card);
    //console.log(card[1].getAttribute('href'));
    //console.log(content[1].getAttribute('id'));
    for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++){
      content[i].classList.remove('active');
      if (card[i].getAttribute('href') === content[i].getAttribute('id')) {
        content[i].classList.add('active');
      }
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let cardCount = 0;
    showContent(){
        const container = document.querySelector('ne-card-slider').shadowRoot;
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('ne-main-content').shadowRoot;
        const card = container.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.anchor');
        const content = wrapper.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.contentMain');
if (cardCount === 0){ content[0].style.visibility = "visible"; cardCount++; } 
else { content[cardCount].style.visibility = "visible"; cardCount++; }
  }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.  Maybe Im not being clear on what I am looking for.  If I click on the first card element, then I want to show the first content element and continue through the list doing the same thing

Comment: Try with varibale you can show one and the next after click.